# How to use lftp to mirror all directories with the same name in source and target

Tags: ftp, lftp

I have folders with the same name on the server and local, where the local folders occasionally update with new files.

I have been using `mirror -R local/folder/a/ remote/folder/a/` to individually update folders which exist in the server, however there are now many folders to do that for which has been time consuming as of late.

All of the folders exist in the same single folder in my local along with other folders which do not exist on the server which I do not want to put in the server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.